# Android Webview back button event

Tags: android, webview, back-button, back

Why doesnt this code work ?

i searched on stackoverflow, tried several codes and they all dont work.

[MainActivity.java]

```
package com.example.jquery;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/framework/lib/homescreen.html");

        return;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

When i press the backbutton the app crashes.

Comment: post the exception report

Comment: Debug error: [DEBUG LOG](http://pastebin.com/q5NBrxKv)

Comment: which line is line 30 in MainActivity?

Comment: Line 30:  if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {

Comment: Is there a specific reason you chose to override onKeyDown() instead of onBackPressed()?

Comment: what code would you recommend ? i tried the onbackpressed too but it gave me an app crash.

Comment: Try my answer. If it crashes, tell me which line causes the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your webView variable to initialize the class variable instead of recreating the Webview variable inside of onCreate().

Change this line:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

To this:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Comment: Tried it, app crashes. has it something to do with this?: WebView webView;

Comment: Which line does it crash on now?

Comment: Looks like your webView is null for some reason when it checks if it can go back. Set a breakpoint on that if check, and see if the webView is null.

Comment: how can i do that? im a web developer, no java developer :| only use the webview for HTML

Comment: Are you in Eclipse? Try just clicking in the left margin where you see the line numbers. A little bug icon should appear. That means a breakpoint is set for that line.

Comment: I think I discovered the source of your null pointer exception. Disregard the need for the breakpoint. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You used a local variable `WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);` in `onCreate` method.